# python syntax error 30/09/2013

Tags: python, syntax-error

My code is returning an error on the line where it says "<= 80" on the = part. Why is that? How can I fix it?

```
#Procedure to find number of books required
def number_books():
    number_books = int(raw_input("Enter number of books you want to order: "))
    price = float(15.99)
    running_total = number_books * price
    return number_books,price

#Procedure to work out discount
def discount(number_books):
    if number_books >= 51 and <= 80:
        discount = running_total / 100 * 10
    elif number_books >= 11 and <=50:
        discount = running_total / 100 * 7.5
    elif number_books >= 6 and <=10:
        discount = running_total / 100 * 5
    elif number_books >=1 and <=5:
        discount = running_total / 100 * 1
    else print "Max number of books available to order is 80. Please re enter number: "        
        return discount

#Calculating final price
def calculation(running_total,discount):
    final_price = running_total - discount

#Display results
def display(final_price)
print "Your order of", number_books, "copies of Computing science for beginners will cost £", final_price 

#Main program
number_books()
discount(number_books)
calculation(running_total,discount)
display(final_price)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: @thegrinner: The syntax is quite obviously wrong, and a common beginners mistake.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, I just want to get the OP in the habit of posting the full error so it won't slow things down if they have more questions in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This is invalid:

```
if number_books >= 51 and <= 80
```

Try:

```
if number_books >= 51 and number_books <= 80
```

The same with all the other occurances thereof

Or, as nneonneo mentions,

```
if 51 <= number_books <= 80
```

Also, you need to return discount the right way at the end (That would be another issue you would encounter once this issue is resolved).

So,

```
def discount(number_books):

    if 51 <= number_books <= 80:
        discount = running_total / 100 * 10
    elif 11 <= number_books <= 50: 
        discount = running_total / 100 * 7.5
    elif 6 <= number_books <= 10: 
        discount = running_total / 100 * 5
    elif 1 <= number_books <= 5:
        discount = running_total / 100 * 1

    return discount


def number_books():
    num_books = int(raw_input("Enter number of books you want to order: "))
    if numb_books <= 0 or num_books > 80:
        print "Max number of books available to order is 80, and minimum is 1. Please re enter number: "        
        number_books()

    price = float(15.99)
    running_total = num_books * price
    return number_books,price
```

Comment: Better yet, `if 51 <= number_books <= 80`

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing range testing, you can use a [*chained comparison*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
if 51 <= number_books <= 80:
```

As to why you get a syntax error: both sides of an `and` (or `or`) operator must be full expressions. Since `<= 80` is not a complete expression, you get a syntax error. You'd need to write `number_books >= 51 and number_books <= 80` to fix that syntax error.

Comment: You might want to link to the documentation here; this feature is called 'chained comparisons'. You did not explain where the OP went wrong in their understanding, however.

Comment: Thanks, added a documentation link.

Comment: Explain a bit more why he is getting the error, because IMO, this currently isn't a proper answer to his question/doubt.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: was working on that edit even as you commented :) Thanks.